# Dynamic Programming Solution- How to solve? (Point me in the right direction)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a question about dynamic programming, from the USACO. (learning computer science).

The question text is located here: http://pastebin.com/MiJ5aEWc

I was thinking this might be analogous to the Max Inc Subsequence, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this from the recent exam?

Comment: Nope, I did take the bronze competition yesterday thought. It was really easy! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can be solved in O(n log n), dynamic programming:
first sort the cows by x-coordinate and map the breed types to integers [1..k]. (k <= n) : O(n log n)
define dp[i] = maximum index j such that from j'th cow to the i'th one all breeds appear or -1 if does not exist.
since for each k <= dp[i] cow range [k,i] is acceptable and i < j -> dp[i] <= dp[j] you can solve the dp part in O(n) by recording number of cows of each type in the cow range [ dp[i], i ].

Comment: I'm confused to the notation around dp[i] range [d , i]. Can you explain what that means? (maybe expand on that part?)

Comment: Edited; acceptable range [a,b] means that range of cows contains all types of breeds.

Comment: Sorry if I'm bothering you, you can stop commenting if you would like, but since dp[i] equals the maximum jth cow, how can "i < j" in the statement " i < j -> dp[i] <= dp[j] ". I definitely understand the part on k <= dp[i], but got any "for-loop" pseudo-code (professor's terminology)? Thanks a ton!

Comment: those i,j are in another scope, you can replace them with x and y: x < y -> dp[x] <= dp[y]